# Get ValidationException in customer Middelware after the Response [response->exception = null]

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I want to modify the Errors fields when I have ValidationException. The problem is when I have ValidationException, the field exception of response variable give me null.

Part of handle function

```php
dd($response);
if(isset($response->exception) && $response->exception instanceof validationException){
    $data = $response->getData();
    $transformedErros = array();
    foreach ($data->error as $field => $value) {
        $transformedField = $transformer::transformedAttribute($field);
        $transformedErros[$transformedField] = str_replace($field, $transformedField, $value);
    }
    $data->error = $transformedErros;
    $response->setData($data);
}
```

[image: Result of dd($response)]

Comment: Can you add your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the exception handler already has handled the exception.

In any case. You error handling should not live in your middleware but in your exception handler. You can register your own exception handler in `bootstrap/app.php` with below code:

```php
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler::class,
    App\Exceptions\Handler::class
);
```

Let `App\Exceptions\Handler` extend `\Laravel\Lumen\Exceptions\Handler` and override what you need to change.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#the-exception-handler to learn more about exception handlers.